# Switching Pages in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am coding a java program and I am new to GUI. I want to know if I can switch to another page on one `JFrame` or not?

Or how can I switch between pages like those in software installation setup?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can switch to a new page by using a `CardLayout`. Take a look at the [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and the [CardLayout API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html). The idea behind this layout is that only one "card" (or otherwise a page) is visible at a given time. This layout thus allows you to switch between different pages in the same window.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the effect of "switching" between two JPanel objects in a JFrame by using the setVisible() command like so:

```
panelA.setVisible(false); //the current JPanel you are switching out of
panelB.setVisible(true); //the JPanel you are switching to
```